# In my source I have two columns: A and B, In my target I have three columns: A, B and C and we have to generate integer value in c colum using source

Tags: sql, informatica

In my source I have two columns: A and B
In my target I have three columns: A, B and C
Source table

```
               A                      B            
               123456                 3             
               12345                  2             
               12345                  1
```

Target table

```
               A                      B             C
               123456                 3             123.456
               12345                  2             123.45
               12345                  1             1234.5
```

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do easily using `POWER( NUMBERS, EXPONENT )` function in Informatica.
Create an expression transformation and calculate column c like this

```
out_C = IIF(ISNULL(B),0, A / (POWER(10,B)))
```

Link `out_C` to Target column C. Link A,B as well. I added if clause to handle null value of B.
**Explanation :** Power function calculates 10 to the power B. So in your example, for first row, column C will be calculated as

```
C= 123456 / (10^3) 
 = 123456 / 1000
 = 123.456
```